# Is it possible to have our most related sites in the footer?

Tags: feature-request

This is probably most importantly answered by @Jin, but in looking at the site design, I find it difficult for users to find our most closely related sites.

Hermeneutics is a very, very close site, but as beta, it technically doesn't make the list. Beyond that, Judaism (Mi Yodeya) and Islam are, IMHO, our closest kin. Often when we say, this question is off-topic, those are the sites that we think are on topic.

One could argue that Philosophy, Skeptics, History, and ELU are also related, but definitely to a differs degree.

The question is, seeing that these sites are so closely related, is it possible to have these appear in our footer?

Comment: Also, philosophy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've recently started categorizing similar sites together in the footer, so that part is [status-completed](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed). But, no, we don't currently have plans to start adding beta sites to the footer.

In reality, the increasing number of sites already makes this a deteriorating solution. Soon we're going to have to come up with a better implementation of what to do with that space.

I'll leave the feature request, but in reality, this subject falls somewhere between [status-bydesign](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and [status-deferred](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred). Sorry I don't have anything more concrete to offer. It's just an issue to be decided.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I understand how difficult it would be - I wonder if maybe we could lean on SE for a solution though.  Just consider having a category under which 'related sites' could have links.  Those links with the most votes (if there was room for say, 6 links, then the top 6 links) would then be shown.  It could be pretty useful!

Comment: @AffableGeek Our current design does not allow for per-site customizations in the footer... or how to select/edit those sites, keep them up to date, consistency issues/enforcement, etc, etc. This is going to take a more comprehensive solution.

Comment: Perhaps it should be a list of the sites that we most migrate to. That is quantifiable and easily coded. It could be completely automatic.

Answer (score 1):

I hope so. It should be that way.